# Joining Attributes by Location (Summary) - Further extension?

Tags: qgis-3, routing

(Using QGIS version 3.28.6-Firenze)

I am trying to aggregate a directional polyline layer, representing route flows ('volume') and  obtain the sum of these by segment **and** by direction.
e.g. I have 4 polyline routes: 1>2, 2>1, 2>3 & 3>2, each with an associated demand:

[image].

In geometry terms, the lines between node pairs can overlap but may be reversed.
I can easily obtain the **2-way** volumes on each of the 3 segments by:

1. Using v.clean to split the routes at the intersection into segments;
2. Using Join attributes by location (summary) to sum up the overlaps; and
3. Deleting the duplicates created (as I only want the final total summed volume on each segment).

...But this is not my goal, which, in this example, would be a resulting polyline layer with 6 features, with the total volume of each segment by direction as attributes.

Is there another extension I can use that provides a summary of attributes matching criteria with conditions (I have tried using the ProcessX plugin Join attributes by Nearest with condition - but unsuccessfully!), or perhaps someone can suggest some SQL - sorry as you can probably guess I am not that familiar with the latter, but am slowly getting there!

(Sample files shown above can be found at:
[Updated Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B1JG7bb-cs-JJ70SPxN-Ts5F0ma8kW3z/view?usp=drive_link))